# How to determine if virtual server was suspended by host using C#

Tags: c#, windows, virtual-machine, suspend, esxi

I'm running into a problem where by my windows 2k8 virtual server is being suspended when it uses too much resources or when the virtual server host (VMware ESXi) is upgpraded and places my VM into a suspended state.

I want to write a small C# console app which sole job is to detect this suspension state after the VMware host resumes the virtual machine.
Currently I need to request logs to tell if the server was suspended from the server ops team.

What telemetry can one use to detect if my OS was suspended at the VMWare host level ?

One solution I have is to: from the virtual server OS, ping another PC with some data, the PC that I ping records the ping. The downside to this approach is I would need to use two apps. I would much prefer a single app running on the virtual server itself intelligent enough to detect a suspension state.

Shout if I need to provide more info or clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Log4net to log whatever happens into a txt file and zip it.

Tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial